# SPARQL Construct Query Incremental variable

Tags: sparql, rdf, ttl

I'm looking to construct a graph with the URI ending in a incremental variable e.g violation1, violation2, violation3....

For example if I have the following data graph.

```
:_b1 ex:violationInfo "mapping violation".
:_b2 ex:violationInfo "data violation".
```

And I would like to construct a graph similar to below.

```
ex:violation1 ex:violationInfo "mapping violation".
ex:violation2 ex:violationInfo "data violation".
```

I have started the following construct query but I can't figure out how to create an incremental variable.

```
CONSTRUCT {
?s ?p ?o }
WHERE {
?s ?p ?o 
}
```

This however gives me the same graph, I can't find information relating to incremental variables.

Comment: of course it gives you the same graph, I mean `?s ?p ?o ` is the most generic triple pattern that just matches all triples in the graph. Also, in SPARQL there is no means of row number or auto id like you might know from SQL. What you could do indeed is to create URIs out of the bnodes if that's sufficient for you

Comment: Thanks for reply. I’m new to SPARQL, how could I make URI’s ending it an incremental variable?

Comment: you can't was what I was trying to say. Or at least I'm not aware of anything. I mean, maybe there is some crazy workaround, but I doubt that this would scale. Like use the number of bnodes that are smaller than your own bnode label to get the position in terms of lexicographical ordering - might work for smaller datasets, though I never tested if this would work at all. But as I said, others might come with a solution, I'm not really an expert